# Check strings equality without direction?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare two strings, while on one of them I'm doing some bidi manipulation:

```
const a = "\u202B" + "hi" + "\u202C"

console.log(a === 'hi') // false
console.log(a == 'hi') // false
```

The output on the screen will look the same while it's actually not. Is there a way to check for equality while not taking bidi into account (so the result of the equality check above will return true)?

Comment: Remove bidi parts from string before comparing. There is no other way.

Comment: The string `"\u202Bhi\u202C"` simply isn't the string `"hi"`. You'd want to strip all bidi and perhaps other "special characters" from the string before comparison…?

Comment: @deceze yes is this possible to strip all bidi?

Comment: also [How can i deal with bidirectional text & numbers in pure JavaScript substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73228179/how-can-i-deal-with-bidirectional-text-numbers-in-pure-javascript-substring-me)